# Woocommerce conditionally load a custom product template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I am creating a custom theme and I have copied the file `content-product.php` to my theme folder.  There I have made changes to the html structure and css.  I can load of list of products and see the changes working via the short code `[products]`.

However elsewhere on the site I want to display another list of products but from a different category. I would use the shortcode `[products category="special category"]` These products should be displayed using a different template.

My question is: Where can I inspect the shortcode query? and how can I conditionally load a different template depending on which products are being displayed?

In my themes `functions.php` file I have started to extend the `[products]` shortcode like this:

```
function my_wc_shortcode_product_query_args($args, $atts){

    if ( isset( $args['category'] ) && $args['category'] == "Daoine Óga") {
        var_dump($args);
    // Tell Woocommerce to load my custom template instead of the my-theme/woocommerce/content-product.php
    }
    return $args;

}
```

But I'm not sure how I can return or get woocommerce to display my custom template at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The woocommerce file that creates the `[products]` shortcode can be found at `plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php`

Make a folder in `plugins` folder called `custom-product-templates` and make a copy of the woocommerce file class-wc-shortcode-products.php to that folder.

Add the plugin comments to the top of that file:

```
/*
Plugin name: Custom Product Template
Plugin URI: https://anirishwebdesigner.com
Description: Display custom product templates in woocommerce loop 
Author: Linda Keating
Author URI: http://anirishwebdesigner.com
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Navigate to `localhost/wp-admin` in browser and to the plugins and activate newly created plugin

I can now safely edit that file so that the shortcode behaviour loads the template I want based on certain criteria.

First extend the class so that it accepts a `template` attribute

In the parse attributes function add

`'template'      => '',`

Then search for `wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');` and modify the code here to load different templates in an `if..else` statement. Something like:

```
`if($this->attributes['template'] == 'Daoine Óga') {
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'childrenproduct' );
     } else {
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
 }`
```

If there are simpler / better solutions please let me know.